# Is it possible to use paravirtualization to share a GPU with a Windows guest to enable gaming on Linux?

Tags: graphics-card, virtualization, gaming, para-virtualization

My objective is to run games on Linux, maximising compatibility by using a real virtualized instance of Windows (e.g. VR, day 1 game launches, things like that).

I understand that you can use PCIe passthrough to pass an entire device to the guest, but my computer only has a single AMD 5700xt GPU (and does not have onboard graphics).

I also understand that workstation cards offer methods similar to AMD or Intel's hardware virtualization (VT-x, etc) allowing for the hardware to be shared with the guest with negligible loss in performance (I believe that Intel's dedicated consumer graphics cards may be the first consumer card to offer this?).

Not owning a workstation card and having onboard graphics, I gave up and just dual boot.

Recently I read about paravirtualization.

I am wondering if there is a method to use paravirtualization to effectively share a GPU from a Linux host to a Windows guest?

Comment: Since no one else has answered or commented, here's my 2 cents: try searching the Unraid OS (proprietary, but linux based) forums, as in passing I've noticed many questions on VMs and GPU passthru. Spaceinvader One on Youtube also has tutorials on Passing through GPUs to VMs and Dockers in Unraid, which may be of interest.

Comment: There's virgil3d, but apparently it's not really working yet on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these is what you're looking for.

https://forum.level1techs.com/t/2-gamers-1-gpu-with-hyper-v-gpu-p-gpu-partitioning-finally-made-possible-with-hyperv/172234

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XLLcc29EZ_8

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1161132)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The links you posted involve having a windows host system.